# How to connect Azure VM to Android App

Tags: android, sql-server, azure

I need to connect an Azure VM to my Android application to read from the `SQL Server` database. I am a noob in Android programming and having looked around, the only thing I could find was the official documentation [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-sql-connect/#create-a-tcp-endpoint-for-the-virtual-machine).

Using this:

`"Server=mycloudservice.cloudapp.net,57500;Integrated Security=false;User ID=<login_name>;Password=<your_password>"` which uses endpoints

Can a connection be made without using endpoints somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint should be created and set up as that is the mandatory for you to being able to access your virtual machine with the SQL Server. So yes, the link you mentioned is the right way to make things done.
The conncetion from Android to the SQL Server, however, is a little different than what you may see in the referenced link. You may refer to [that good SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26052899/connecting-android-app-to-microsoft-sql-server-2008) for the approach.

You may want to try [Azure SQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/) as an alternative (it can be called... SQL Server as a service, but with some differences), but you will need to set up the allowed IP address that will be able to connect to the Azure SQL