# Android App error connecting to Azure SQL DB via ms jdbc

Tags: android, azure, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I am new to Android app development and I'm trying to connect to an Azure SQL DB with the native MS JDBC driver (sqljdbc4.jar) and I keep on getting the following error:

"Error connection: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Socket closed"."

i am able to connect to the DB with the same connectionstring with squirrel though.

i use android studio 2.1.3 and i am really at the end of my wits...
here is the code:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver());
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
String username = "<>";
String password = "<>";
java.sql.Connection DbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://<myserver>:1433;databaseName=thumbsupp;user=" + username + ";password=" + password + ";encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;");
```

i even tried to open a socket on port 1433 in code:

```
SocketFactory sf = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sf.createSocket("<myserver>", 1433);
HostnameVerifier hverify = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
SSLSession ssoc = socket.getSession();
```

but to no prevail although I get `true` when calling

```
hverify.verify();
```

Am I missing some configurations from Android Studio?

edit: if a check the enabled protocols on the socket:

```
socket.getEnabledProtocols();
```

the only protocols i get back are TLS1.0, TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 ??

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are many SO/MSDN threads which have the same issue. Meanwhile, a workaround way is that using jTDS Driver instead of MS SQL Server JDBC Driver.

Please refer to these threads below to solve your issue.

1. [Sql Database connect Using the JDBC Driver with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934090/sql-database-connect-using-the-jdbc-driver-with-android)
2. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4799819a-27fd-4292-a3d8-f114207c20b2/using-the-jdbc-driver-with-android?forum=sqldataaccess
3. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nickhodge/2010/01/25/jdbc-to-sql-azure/

Hope it helps.